# Use SQL to generate string

Tags: mysql, sql

**Sample Table**

```
---------------------------                  --------
| id | user |  num | type | ---> Want to get | name |
---------------------------                  --------
| 5  |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2A  |
---------------------------                  --------
| 10 |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2B  |
---------------------------                  --------
| 11 |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2C  |
---------------------------                  --------
| 12 |  2   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2A  |
---------------------------                  --------
| 14 |  1   |   3  |  R   |                  | R3A  |
---------------------------                  --------
| 17 |  2   |   3  |  R   |                  | R3A  |
---------------------------                  --------
```

**Explanation**

I have a simple database schema as shown on the left. I need to use SQL to generate the given name column based on the values. I have already figured out how to `CONCAT(type,num)`, but I'm at a loss for how to generate the correct letter. I know something like this is possible in SQL because I've done something similar a long time ago.

**Numbering scheme**
For each user, as more rows with the same `num` and `type` are found, the letters should progress from A-Z. There will never be more that 26 so dealing with that is not an issue

I think I can first generate numbers (ie 1,2,3 instead of A,B,C) and then do something along the lines of `SELECT 1 FROM [A..Z]`, I'm just not sure how to accomplish this in MySQL.

**UPDATE**

```
If I can get from here:                   To:
---------------------------                  --------------
| id | user |  num | type |                  | name | seq |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 5  |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2   |  1  |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 10 |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2   |  2  |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 11 |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2   |  3  |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 12 |  2   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q2   |  1  |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 14 |  1   |   3  |  R   |                  | R3   |  1  |
---------------------------                  --------------
| 17 |  2   |   3  |  R   |                  | R3   |  1  |
---------------------------                  --------------
Then its just a simple matter of using CHAR()
```

Comment: Can you provide more sample data?  Will you also have Q3A, B, and C?

Comment: What is the logic for assigning the letter?  It is not obvious from your example.

Comment: `| 11 |  1   |   2  |  Q   |                  | Q3A  |` ???

Comment: @DoSparKot typo, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT
  id, user, num, type, seq
FROM (
SELECT
  sample.*,
  @row:= case when @lst_type=type
                   and @lst_user=user
                   and @lst_num=num then @row+1 else 65 end,
  CONCAT(type, num, CHAR(@row)) seq,
  @lst_type:=type,
  @lst_user:=user,
  @lst_num:=num
FROM sample, (select @lst_type:=null,
                     @lst_user:=null,
                     @lst_num:=null, 
                     @row:=65) r
ORDER BY id
) s
```

please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e457/1).

Comment: +1 -- Even if this isn't what OP wants (who knows?), love the use of CHAR!

Comment: Yes, this answer has provided much insight but I accidentally left out a detail that makes this solution not quite work :(

Comment: @sgeddes thanks :) it was a long time since I wasn't using CHAR :)

Comment: @parker.sikand I see that you have updated your question, and now I don't understand the logic... why Q2A, Q2B, and then Q3A?

Comment: @parker.sikand okay, it was a typo, now i got it

Comment: @fthiella: I think if `user,num,type` are *repeating* then it goes like `A,B,C`. Not sure what he needs if he gets more than 26 duplicates for that combination.

Comment: @kaf yes you are correct. I had originally left out that detail when fthiella made this answer. My mistake.

Comment: @parker.sikand now it should be okay

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect man, much appreciated. Know any good docs or tutorials for this kinda stuff?